# Accessing a property of a private set property in initialization

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to create a ViewModel that is easier to use in my View than the model it is based off of (which is a highly hierarchical datatype).  I found myself writing Razor code that looked like:

```
<label asp-for="Audit.Stages.First(s => s.Stage == AuditStageType.INITIAL_REVIEW).Decision">Initial Recommendation:&nbsp;</label>
@(Model.Audit.Stages.First(s => s.Stage == AuditStageType.INITIAL_REVIEW).Decision?.Recommendation ?? ViewBag.Empty)
```

This was a pain, so I've been working on flattening out the model, but I need to make sure initialization can't happen in ways that would break the assumptions of the model.

So, in my ViewModel, I'm trying to do:

```
public Audit Audit { get; private set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets the Initial Review stage from the Audit object
/// </summary>
public AuditStage Stage1
{
    get
    {
        return Audit.Stages.First(s => s.Stage == AuditStageType.INITIAL_REVIEW);
    }
}
```

And then in my underlying model I do:

```
public class Audit : EntityBase
{
    public Audit()
    {
        CurrentStatus = null;
        EmpPhone = null;
        Stages = new List<AuditStage>()
        {
            new AuditStage()
            {
                Stage = AuditStageType.INITIAL_REVIEW
            }
        };
    }
    //so that the Stages object can't get reset
    public ICollection<AuditStage> Stages { get; private set; }
}
```

and I want to allow an object initializer to initialize other parts of the object, like:

```
SurveyAnswers sa = surveyAnswersRepository.GetById(id);
Employee emp;
try
{
    emp = employeeRepository.GetById(sa.Sme.SiteUser.EmployeeId ?? 0);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    emp = null;
}

AuditViewModel model = new AuditViewModel()
{
    //all of these lines throw an error of "An object reference is required
    //for the non-static field, method, or property 'Audit.X'"
    Audit.Answers = sa,
    Audit.CurrentStatus = emp?.CurrentStatus,
    Audit.EmpPhone= emp?.PhoneNumber
};
```

So, it looks like the `private set` is keeping me from accessing the object in any way in the object initializer.
I would rather use object initializers than separate constructors for each possible combination of information I might be given (like emp and sa; there are others).

And I would rather use object initializers than having to call

```
model.Audit.Answers = sa;
model.Audit.PayGrade = emp?.PayGrade;
model.Audit.PayStep = emp?.PayStep;
```

after initialization, since it's cleaner to have it all in the same code block.

**Is there a way I can use an object initializer to access a property of a property that I want to protect from bad initialization?**  Am I thinking about this all wrong?  That's entirely possible; I'm still pretty new to C# and especially MVC.

Comment: It's not up to you to protect a property of a property from bad initialization. It's a class's job to protect its *own* properties from bad initialization. `Audit` should have a constructor that takes appropriate parameters and does appropriate validation. Why should *anybody* who creates an `Audit` have to reimplement the validation? Any code that creates an `Audit` has to go through one point: `Audit`'s constructors. Anything required for initializing an `Audit` should therefore go there. Nobody has to do anything special to get it, nobody can forget to call it.

Comment: What you're contemplating is the programming equivalent of telling your roommate to break up with his girlfriend. Stay out of it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett what you're saying sounds like I should be just making everything in `Audit` have private setters, and don't let anyone do extra initialization outside the constructors.  Since the class is part of our team's public API, it would take a lot of work to keep from breaking others' code.

Comment: Not at all. I'm saying that if you need to "protect a property from bad initialization", the first choice of a place to do that is in a constructor.